# Async call hangs in Windows service, same code doesn't hang in console application

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, async-await

I have the following method that lives in an assembly that is referenced by a Windows service.  The service uses a FileSystemWatcher to wait for a file to be dropped.  When a new file arrives some logic is applied (if it helps to know, the logic is checking to see if a file already exists in Google Drive with the same name as the file just dropped.  If so, the existing file is Trashed and the newly dropped file will eventually take its place after it has been converted to the Google format).  Finally the service connects to the Drive API using a wrapper I wrote (this wrapper is named 'service' in the method below).

The problem is that when I use this same assembly from a Console app it works fine.  When the service runs it makes it to the two logging statements under the //debugging comment and then just hangs.

My question: How can I figure out why this code hangs in a service and not in a console app?

```
private async Task<bool> RunConverter( JobLogging logging ) {
            try {
                logging.Log( "Converting file", JobLogging.Verbosity.Information );
                var service = new Service( _clientID, _clientSecret );

                // debugging
                logging.Log( "ClientID: " + _clientID, JobLogging.Verbosity.All );
                logging.Log( "ClientSecret: " + _clientSecret, JobLogging.Verbosity.All );

                await service.Connect();
                logging.Log( "Service connected", JobLogging.Verbosity.All );

                // convert and make files public 
                var fileCount = await service.ConvertFiles( logging );

                if ( fileCount > 0 ) ClearPPTX( logging );
                return true;
            }
            catch ( Exception ex ) {
                logging.Log( "Exception during File Conversion: " + ex.Message, JobLogging.Verbosity.Critical, true );
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why it would hang, but check to ensure the _account_ the Windows service is running in has `file access permissions` to the folder your are monitoring

Comment: @Micky, the service is running as Local System but I've tried Local Service, Network Service and my own domain admin credentials all to no avail.  The files are moved between folders successfully but the service.Connect() call that connects to the Drive API hangs.

Comment: Can you configure your program to not use Google drive and test it?  Google drives have some security 'issues'.

Comment: Is it a WCF service or a classic Windows service? Do you see a non-null synchronization context if you check `SynchronizationContext.Current` at the beginning of `RunConverter`?

Comment: Noseratio, the service is a classic Windows service.  Just getting back to this, I'm going to check the SynchronizationContext, thanks!

Comment: Steve Wellens, could you elaborate a bit on the security "issues" you're referring to?  The code runs fine if I'm running it as a console application on either my development machine or in production environment, just not when I encase the logic in a service and run it that way.  Development environment is a Win 7 46 bit machine, production is a Win 2008 r2 64 bit server.